# How to troubleshoot "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, silverstripe

I have a `Silverstripe` website connected to `MySql` server version 5.6.17 hosted on `Rackspace`

I'm struggling with 2 errors that happen in sync from time to time but I can't figure out what's the root cause.

```
Error: Couldn't run query: COMMIT; Lost connection to MySQL server during query
At line 598 in /home/dployio/deployments/production/1733814/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php
SS_CustomLogErrorEmailFormatter->format(Array) 
Custom_SS_LogEmailWriter.php:43
Custom_SS_LogEmailWriter->_write(Array) 
Abstract.php:85
Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract->write(Array) 
Log.php:428
Zend_Log->log(Array,3,) 
Log.php:178
SS_Log::log(Array,3) 
Debug.php:301
Debug::fatalHandler(256,Couldn't run query: COMMIT; Lost connection to MySQL server during query,/home/dployio/deployments/production/1733814/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php,598,Array) 
Debug.php:553
errorHandler(256,Couldn't run query: COMMIT; Lost connection to MySQL server during query,/home/dployio/deployments/production/1733814/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php,598) 
MySQLDatabase.php:598
MySQLDatabase->databaseError(Couldn't run query: COMMIT; Lost connection to MySQL server during query,256) 
MySQLDatabase.php:150
MySQLDatabase->query(COMMIT;,256) 
DB.php:208
DB::query(COMMIT;) 
SapphireTransactionManager.php:69
SapphireTransactionManager->commit() 
SapphireTransactionManager.php:99
SapphireTransactionManager->transaction(Closure$NewsRequestManager::postNews;280716067)
```

and then

```
Error: Couldn't run query: INSERT INTO "News_Tags" ("NewsID","TagID") VALUES (91, 1225) Table './os_production/News_Tags' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
At line 598 in /home/dployio/deployments/production/1733814/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php
SS_CustomLogErrorEmailFormatter->format(Array) 
Custom_SS_LogEmailWriter.php:43
Custom_SS_LogEmailWriter->_write(Array) 
Abstract.php:85
Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract->write(Array) 
Log.php:428
Zend_Log->log(Array,3,) 
Log.php:178
SS_Log::log(Array,3) 
Debug.php:301
Debug::fatalHandler(256,Couldn't run query: INSERT INTO "News_Tags" ("NewsID","TagID") VALUES (91, 1225) Table './os_production/News_Tags' is marked as crashed and should be repaired,/home/dployio/deployments/production/1733814/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php,598,Array) 
Debug.php:553
errorHandler(256,Couldn't run query: INSERT INTO "News_Tags" ("NewsID","TagID") VALUES (91, 1225) Table './os_production/News_Tags' is marked as crashed and should be repaired,/home/dployio/deployments/production/1733814/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php,598) 
MySQLDatabase.php:598
MySQLDatabase->databaseError(Couldn't run query: INSERT INTO "News_Tags" ("NewsID","TagID") VALUES (91, 1225) Table './os_production/News_Tags' is marked as crashed and should be repaired,256) 
MySQLDatabase.php:150
MySQLDatabase->query(INSERT INTO "News_Tags" ("NewsID","TagID") VALUES (91, 1225),256) 
DB.php:208
DB::query(INSERT INTO "News_Tags" ("NewsID","TagID") VALUES (91, 1225)) 
UnitOfWork.php:415
UnitOfWork->commit() 
SapphireTransactionManager.php:62
```

First error happens when inserting a record on table (`News`) which contains no more than 100 records. This table contains a fulltext index over a couple of fields (`mediumtext` type all of them).

Second query it's trying to insert related news tags

Big problem here is that once this happens, a fulltext index related to this needs to be regenerated to make this module work again. This means, once this pairs of errors happens, something breaks permanently.

This is the fulltext index definition

```
FULLTEXT INDEX Headline_SummaryHtmlFree_BodyHtmlFree 
(Headline, SummaryHtmlFree, BodyHtmlFree);
```

Things I've tried (that obviously didn't help)

- Repair `News_Tags` table since it talks about a crashed state
- Played with package size since some places mention this as a potential cause
- Asked Rackspace for server error log and found nothing relevant
- Run query that fails to execute from PHP on mysql console, and **it succeeded** so maybe there is something to change on client side

As I mentioned before, what does fix this problem is recreating fulltext index `Headline_SummaryHtmlFree_BodyHtmlFree` but I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you running the web server and MySQL on the same box?

Comment: @Machavity: no, they are not in the same box

Comment: How long does that first query take to execute?

Comment: Nothing, it's very quick. It's an insert on table with no more than 100 records. Text being sent doesn't seem to be relevant, it fails with long and short texts.

Comment: I've seen that error happen on long-running scripts where it was downloading a large file from an external source or something and the mysqli connection was timing out. In that case it was with a Rackspace CloudDB. This sounds like it's in the context of a reasonably short web request though, correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, there is no long query. BTW, this is also a Rackspace cloud database

Comment: Are you on Silverstripe 3.1 or 3.2? If it's an option you might try switching to 3.2 which uses PDO instead of mysqli. Or you might try changing mysqli.reconnect = Off to On in php.ini. I don't think this is an issue with Silverstripe particularly but I did see some people theorizing that it may be an issue with some of PHP's native drivers.

Comment: I'm using silverstripe 3.1. Something that makes hard troubleshooting is that problem disappears once I rebuild fulltext index and I don't know how to trigger it to test different approaches (I'll see to take a db backup next time). It might take a month to show up again. In any case, I'll research about your suggestions and see if we can apply any of them to see how it goes. Thanks!